# How to get stma- ltma crossover if i have stma and ltma values in seperate lists in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

A crossover occurs at day `i` if only if `STMA(i)` and `LTMA(i)` both are defined at days `i` and `i-1`, and either one of the below conditions is fulfilled:

```
STMA(i-1) > LTMA(i-1) and  STMA(i) <= LTMA(i)

STMA(i-1) < LTMA(i-1) and  STMA(i) >= LTMA(i)

STMA(i-1) = LTMA(i-1) and  STMA(i) != LTMA(i)
```

how to get the values of `i` for crossover ?

Comment: *How to get the values of trying it yourself*? And paste your code when you finished attempting at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i think u are looking below thing


______________
#!/bin/python3

import sys


n = int(input().strip())
p = list(map(int, input().strip().split(' ')))
num_stma = 60
num_ltma = 300
min_days = max(num_stma, num_ltma)


def stma(day):
    min_index = day - num_stma
    return sum(p[min_index:day]) / num_stma

def ltma(day):
    min_index = day - num_ltma
    return sum(p[min_index:day]) / num_ltma

def rule1(day):
    [ltma_y, stma_y] = [ltma(day-1), stma(day-1)]
    [ltma_t, stma_t] = [ltma(day), stma(day)]

    return stma_y > ltma_y and stma_t <= ltma_t

def rule2(day):
    [ltma_y, stma_y] = [ltma(day-1), stma(day-1)]
    [ltma_t, stma_t] = [ltma(day), stma(day)]

    return stma_y < ltma_y and stma_t >= ltma_t

def rule3(day):
    [ltma_y, stma_y] = [ltma(day-1), stma(day-1)]
    [ltma_t, stma_t] = [ltma(day), stma(day)]

    return stma_y == ltma_y and stma_t != ltma_t

def crossover(day):
    return rule1(day) or rule2(day) or rule3(day)


for i in range(min_days + 1, n + 1):
    if crossover(i):
        print("{0} {1:.2f} {2:.2f}".format(i, stma(i), ltma(i)))
```